# phpstorm: Difficulty in setting up local server on PHP STorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Am new to phpstorm and  have been trying to setup my local server but to no avail. I just downloaded the app today and would appreciate if anyone could provide me with an insight. thanks.

Comment: If you want to use the built-in webserver, check their [Help Article](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/php-built-in-web-server.html) first. Is there a more specific question you have?

Answer (score 0):

File->New Profile From Existing File->Web Server is installed locally->(Choose your destination folder->(click on Project root{located on the same page})->Choose Your Webserver{local host}
Note: That the folder path will be automatically appended to the